# HttpException: Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8983: Connection refused

Tags: symfony, solr

I try to configure NelmioSolariumBundle in symfony2 but i have this error:

```
HttpException: Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8983: Connection refused
```

I added this section in the file config.yml :

```
nelmio_solarium:
    endpoints:
        default:
            host: %solr_host%
            port: %solr_port%
            path: %solr_path%
            core: %solr_core%
            timeout: %solr_timeout%
    clients:
        default:
            endpoints: [default]
```

and this in parametre.yml:

```
solr_host: 127.0.0.1
    solr_port: 8983
    solr_path: /solr/
    solr_core: allTest
    solr_timeout: 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, your Solr server is down. Please check the Solr logs if the startup has failed.

```
tail -n 200 /tmp/solr.log # or wherever Solr writes its logs
```

This can happen if you have an error in your schema.xml, your solrconfig.xml, or when a file should be included which doesn't exist.

Comment: I do not know I should excute this command because I work on windows

Comment: Ok, sorry. But you did install a standalone Solr server, right? Solr is a Java application, and depending on its configuration, it should write a log file somewhere. The command I proposed would print the last 200 lines in a Linux/Unix shell, but you can as well open it in a (proper) text editor and see if there are any errors in the last ~200 lines.

Comment: I searched in the /vendor/solarium and I did not find the log file

Comment: Did you download and install a Solr server? https://lucene.apache.org/solr/downloads.html

Comment: I use composer to download bundle
"nelmio/solarium-bundle": "2.*"

Comment: Ok, once more: Solr is a *standalone* server. Solarium is only a *client* for that server. You need to download, install, configure and start a Solr server. The Solr server itself is not part of the Solarium project.

Comment: but just follow the steps that are in this link to git: https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSolariumBundle

Comment: Boy, do you even know what Solr is?