# The requested URL /solr/admin/ping was not found on this server

Tags: php, symfony, solr

I am using `nelmio/solarium-bundle`. I have configured this bundle but I have error in running this test file:

> Symfony/vendor/solarium/solarium/examples/1.1-check-solarium-and-ping.php

This is error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Solarium\Exception\HttpException' with message ' in C:\wamp\www\Symfony2\vendor\solarium\solarium\library\Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result.php on line 103

Solarium\Exception\HttpException: Solr HTTP error: OK (404) <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN"> <html><head> <title>404 Not Found</title> </head><body> <h1>Not Found</h1> <p>The requested URL /solr/admin/ping was not found on this server.</p> <hr> <address>Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at 127.0.0.1 Port 80</address> </body></html> in C:\wamp\www\Symfony2\vendor\solarium\solarium\library\Solarium\Core\Query\Result\Result.php on line 103
```

This is the bundle's configuration in my `config.yml`:

```
nelmio_solarium: ~
```

I have modified `config.dist.php` file :

```
$config = array(
    'endpoint' => array(
        'localhost' => array(
            'host' => '127.0.0.1',
            'port' => null,
            'path' => '/solr',
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [HttpException: Solr HTTP error: HTTP request failed, Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8983: Connection refused](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597255/httpexception-solr-http-error-http-request-failed-failed-to-connect-to-127-0)

Comment: You still haven't set up your Solr server, have you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25597255/httpexception-solr-http-error-http-request-failed-failed-to-connect-to-127-0

Comment: The fact that you've installed a Solr client bundle in Symfony has nothing to do with running the Solr server itself. Once again: Solr is a *standalone server*. Solarium is only a *client* for that server. The NelmioSolariumBundle does *not* contain a Solr server. You need to download, install, configure and start a Solr server.

Answer (score 3):

why your port is null it should by something like 8983.